# Filter Function in DAX wouldn't allow simple math operation on Date

Tags: formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to compute Week over Week values for Sales (GMS) by passing a parameter for the weekend date. While the Sales for the current week are computed correctly using this formula:

```
Sales_CW = 
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales_Table[gms]), 
FILTER(Sales_Table,Sales_Table[weeks] = WEEKNUM(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate]))),
FILTER(Sales_Table,Sales_Table[year] = YEAR(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate]))))
```

The following formula with a -1 in the first filte errors out:

```
Sales_LW = 
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales_Table[gms]), 
FILTER(Sales_Table,Sales_Table[weeks] = WEEKNUM(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate]))-1), 
FILTER(Sales_Table,Sales_Table[year] = YEAR(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate]))))
```

The reason I am using the FILTER function is to accept the parameter value in the measure definition. I don't get what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sales_LW = 
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales_Table[gms]), 
FILTER(Sales_Table,Sales_Table[weeks] = WEEKNUM(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate]))-1 &&
Sales_Table[year] = YEAR(MAX(Query1[WeekendDate])))
```